# Javascriptで特定のカラーを全て他の色に置き換えるには？

Tags: javascript, css

以下のHTMLとCSSがあるとき、Javascriptで `#FF0000` を `#0000FF` に変更するには
すべての要素を繰り返し処理で回し、さらにcolorやborder-color、background-colorの
一つ一つの要素の中を覗いて書き換える方法しか思いつかないのですが、もうすこし
効率の良い方法はありますか？

また、`:after` や `:before` で定義した色については差し替え不能だと思うのですが、可能ですか？

追記：
JavascriptでDOMのクラスを書き換えることで実現する方法が紹介されましたが
そうすると置換したい色の数だけCSSの定義を増やさなければならなくなるため
sassを利用したスマートな解決方法などもございましたら
是非教えていただきたいです。

---

**HTML**

```
<h1>hoge</h1>
<p>piyo</p>
<div>fuga</div>
<span>hena</span>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  background: #FF0000;
}

p {
  color: #FF0000;
}

div {
  border: solid 1px #FF0000;
}

span:after {
  content: 'after:';
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: クラス付けしておいてクラスを切り替えるのはだめなのですか？

Comment: 切り替えたい色の数が4色存在するのですがCSSを
h1.red{ background: #FF0000; }
h1.blue{ background: #00FF00; }
h1.green{ background: #0000FF; }
h1.yellow{ background: #FFFF00; }
のように色の数だけ定義するということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。切り替えスタイルをあらかじめ用意しておいてjavascriptでは、タグのクラスを置き換えるという意味です。

Comment: 要素の数が掛け算でのっかってくるので、もう少しスマートに実現する方法は無いでしょうか。

Comment: 実際に用意する色数はたかだか限られていると思うし、それぞれのスタイルの作成については単純にエディタで置き換えして(あるいは事前にプログラム的にで)作成できると思います。

Comment: sass初心者なのですが、sassを利用したエレガントな方法をご存知でしたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 以前の質問でsassは静的に作成するので無理という結論だったのでは？

Comment: スタイルシートのテンプレートを持っていてそれで動的に作成したスタイルシートで置き換えるということもできるような気がします。（ブラウザ依存かも）

Comment: 今書いたコード(クラス指定を書き換える方法)は sass にすることによってさらにシンプルにはなりますが、 sass を使うことによって、最終的なCSSクラスの定義数が減るということはないです。ループでもいいような。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

設定した色の値自体を変えるのは面倒なので、ごくごく普通に複数CSSセレクタに対する一括指定をする方法が良いと思います。

### 方法1: CSS クラス指定での切り替え

やり方としては以下のようにします。

1. 上書きルールセットとして CSS クラスを作成しておき、
2. 対象になる要素全体を別の要素で囲んで、
3. その要素に対する CSS クラス指定だけを変更

```css
h1 { background: #FF0000; }
p { color: #FF0000; }
div { border: solid 1px #FF0000; }
span:after { content: 'after:'; color: #FF0000; }

#root.red h1, #root.red p, #root.red div, #root.red span:after { color: #FF0000; }
#root.green h1, #root.green p, #root.green div, #root.green span:after { color: #00FF00; }
#root.blue h1, #root.blue p, #root.blue div, #root.blue span:after { color: #0000FF; }
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <h1>hoge</h1>
  <p>piyo</p>
  <div>fuga</div>
  <span>hena</span>
</div>

<button onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('root').className='red';">red</button>
<button onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('root').className='green';">green</button>
<button onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('root').className='blue';">blue</button>
```

もちろん、CSS を直接書き換える手段としては、 [document.StyleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) プロパティが存在していますが、ブラウザによって実装が違うので、モダンなブラウザ限定＋実証されたライブラリを通して使うという条件でないと使うのは[怖い感じがします](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)。[）'0'（](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)

---

**追記:**

そうですか・・・では、 [document.StyleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) を使う例は以下になります。

### 方法2: CSS ルールを書き換える

`getCSSRule()` 関数は、[紹介した記事](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)の物を使っています。

```js
function getCSSRule(ruleName, deleteFlag) { 
    ruleName = ruleName.toLowerCase(); 
    if (document.styleSheets) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) { 
        var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i]; 
        var ii = 0; 
        var cssRule = false; 
        do { 
          if (styleSheet.cssRules) { 
            cssRule = styleSheet.cssRules[ii]; 
          } else { 
            cssRule = styleSheet.rules[ii]; 
          } 
          if (cssRule) { 
            if (cssRule.selectorText.toLowerCase() == ruleName) { 
              if (deleteFlag == 'delete') { 
                if (styleSheet.cssRules) { 
                  styleSheet.deleteRule(ii); 
                } else { 
                  styleSheet.removeRule(ii); 
                } 
                return true; 
              } else { 
                return cssRule; 
              } 
            } 
          } 
          ii++; 
        } while (cssRule) 
      } 
    } 
    return false; 
  } 

function killCSSRule(ruleName) { 
    return getCSSRule(ruleName, 'delete'); 
  } 

function addCSSRule(ruleName) { 
  if (document.styleSheets) { 
    if (!getCSSRule(ruleName)) { 
      if (document.styleSheets[0].addRule) { 
        document.styleSheets[0].addRule(ruleName, null, 0); 
      } else { 
        document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(ruleName + ' { }', 0); 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  return getCSSRule(ruleName); 
}
```

```css
h1 { background: #FF0000; }
div { border: solid 1px #FF0000; }
span:after { content: 'after:'; }

.coloring { color: #FF0000; }
```

```html
<h1 class="coloring">hoge</h1>
<p class="coloring">piyo</p>
<div class="coloring">fuga</div>
<span class="coloring">hena</span>

<button onClick="javascript:getCSSRule('.coloring').style.color = '#FF0000';">red</button>
<button onClick="javascript:getCSSRule('.coloring').style.color = 'green';">green</button>
<button onClick="javascript:getCSSRule('.coloring').style.color = 'blue';">blue</button>
```

自分としてはまだ怖い使い方なので、使用されるブラウザを限定しない限りは、この方法を推奨しません。

Comment: とてもわかりやすいご解説ありがとうございました！
タイトルに一番適切な解答だと思われるため、ベストアンサーにさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

[document.StyleSheetsからスタイルシートにアクセスできますので](http://ash.jp/web/css/js_style.htm)、正規表現などでcssTextを置換すればよいかと思います。

## 実装例

```
for (var i = 0; document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < ss.cssRules.length; j++) {
        var r = ss.cssRules[j];

        r.style.cssText = r.style.cssText.replace(/rgb\(255, 0, 0\)/, '#00f');
    }
}
```

留意点としては以下の通りです。

1. クロスドメインアクセスが出来ない。(Firefoxの既定の動作では)
2. CSSテキストはブラウザによる解釈後の値になる。

特に2は実装上危険なので、styleSheetsを弄るのであればcssTextの値を入力として利用する必要のない処理にすべきだと思います。

Comment: つまり、すべての要素を繰り返し処理で回して一つ一つ書き換えるということでしょうか。その際、:afterや:beforeについての色を変更することはできますでしょうか。

Comment: いえ、スタイルシート内のルールをJavaScriptで書き換えるという意味です。サンプルを書いてみますね。

Comment: こちらの手段が一番望んでいたものなのですが
留意点を教えていただいたことで
この方法は実用的でないと判断することが出来ました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Sassで

```
// .scss
$class_names: red, green, blue;
$class_colors: #FF0000, #00FF00, #0000FF;

@each $class_name in $class_names {
  $index_key: index($class_names, $class_name);

  #root.#{$class_name} {
    h1, p, div, span:after {
      color: nth($class_colors, $index_key);
    }
  }
}
```

と書くと、以下のような .cssを出力できます。
切り替えは他の方が書いているようにDOMのCSSクラス名の変更で行ってください。

```
// .css
#root.red h1, #root.red p, #root.red div, #root.red span:after { color: #FF0000; }
#root.green h1, #root.green p, #root.green div, #root.green span:after { color: #00FF00; }
#root.blue h1, #root.blue p, #root.blue div, #root.blue span:after { color: #0000FF; }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの手段を使わせていただきたいと思います。