# DIV要素にonloadの代用になるものはありますか？

Tags: javascript, html, css

div要素にonloadを付けたいのですが、残念ながら現在の時点ではdivにonloadは付けれません。
ですが、divにonloadなる物を付けたいのですが、何か代用できる方法などはございますでしょうか？
私がやりたいことは、「onload指定している箇所が読み込まれた後、他の要素を表示する」事です。

```
<style>
.main_off {
  display: none;
}
.main_on {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
function main_on(){
  document.getElementById('main').className = "main_on"; 
}
</script>
<noscript>
<style>
  .main_off { display: block; }
</style>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <!-- 画像のonloadイベントで本文のcssを変更 -->
  <img src="abcd.jpg" onload="main_on();" />
</header>

<section id="main" class="main_off" >
  本文
</section>
```

上記のサンプルコードの処理をdivでやりたいと思っておりますが、私の知識では実現できなかったので、皆様のお力をお貸しいただければと思っております。
ご返答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 7):

`<div>` からは、 `'load'` イベントが発生することはありませんので、単純にイベントを取る方法で実現はできません。質問を読む限りでは、もし、仮に「**`<div>` のロード完了**」のイベントがあったとしても、その定義は、質問者が実現しようとしていることとは異なる気がします。

「**`<div>` のロード完了**」の定義があるとすれば...

#### ■ ...それを、「`<div>` 要素がブラウザによって読み込まれた時」とするなら、

```html
<div>brabrabrabrabra</div>
<script>doSomething();</script>
```

として、`<div>` が読み込まれた直後に、コードが実行されるようにしてください。

#### ■ ... それを、「 `<div>` 要素のレンダリングが完了した時」 と定義するなら、

これは、大抵の場合「 `<div>` の見た目に影響する全てのリソースが読み込まれた時」となりますから、 CSS ファイルの読み込み後、及び、 JavaScript UI ライブラリの読み込み後、にコードが実行されなければなりません。まずは、 `</body>` の前にコードをおいてみることから始めることになると思います。

```html
  ...
  <script>doSomething();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### ■ ... それを、 `<div>` 内の `<img>` が読み込みを終了した時とするなら、

`<div>` 内の全ての `<img>` 要素について `'load'` イベントを監視し、全画像リソースの読み込み完了を待ってから、処理が始まるようにコードを書くことになります。 jQuery を使えば、以下のようになります。（ちと汚いですが）

*`<div>` の中の全画像の読込を待ってから `div.onload()` が呼ばれるコード*:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// 要素内の IMG の読み込み後にonload 関数を呼び出させるようにする
jQuery.fn.extend({
  enable_onload_for_images: function() {
    var div = this[0];
    var imgs = this.find("img");
    var count = imgs.length;
    if (count==0 && div.onload)
      div.onload.call(div, count);
    var loaded = 0;
    imgs.one("load", function (e) {
      // イメージが読み込まれた
      loaded++;
      if (loaded === count && div.onload)
        div.onload.call(div, count);
    }).each(function () {
      if ( this.complete || this.readyState === 4) $(this).load();
    });
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ドキュメント中の 全てのdiv[.onload-on-img-onload] をスキャンし、 onload を有効にする
  var divs = $(".onload-on-img-onload");
  divs.each(function () { $(this).enable_onload_for_images(); });
});
</script>
<div class='onload-on-img-onload' onload="window.alert('all resources loaded')">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
    <img src="http://en.wahooart.com/Art.nsf/O/8XX79N/$File/James-E.-Buttersworth-Clipper-in-a-Heavy-Sea.JPG" />
    <img src="http://en.wahooart.com/Art.nsf/O/8XX79N/$File/James-E.-Buttersworth-Clipper-in-a-Heavy-Sea.JPG" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamoto 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。

■ ... それを、 <div> 内の <img> が読み込みを終了した時とするなら、

<div> 内の全ての <img> 要素に onload を定義しておき、全ての画像リソースの読み込み完了を待ってから、処理が始まるようにコードを書くことになります。 <<

とございますが、div要素の中にimg要素が入っていなければこの処理は成し得ないということでございますか？

Comment: 結局、`<div>` の中に非同期読み込みをするタグが含まれている場合、その読み込みが終了したことを取るためには、コードを書く人がそれらをいちいち指定してあげる必要がある、ということです。div に非同期読み込みをする要素が何もなければ一番目の方法でよいでしょう。 /// `<body onload="">` の動作と同じになる方法が一番目のコードになりますが、`<img>` タグがあった場合はタグ自体の読み込み完了は取れているけれど、当然ながら、その定義から読み込まれる画像リソースの完了は待たないことを注意してください。画像リソースの完了については、 `<img>` タグに聞かなければなりません。 /// でもああ結局コードが欲しいと思うので、なんか書いてみます。

Comment: サンプルまでご提供いただきありがとうございます。
上記コードを試してみましたが、動作してくれませんでした。
<div class='onload-on-img-onload' onload="window.alert('all resources loaded')">
これは先に読み込ませたい要素に書き込めばよろしかったですか？

Comment: JavaScript のコードでは、 読み込まれた HTML から対象の `<div>` を探すので、 JavaScript 部分が後ろで実行されるようにしてください。ファイル最後の `</body>` の前か、もしくは、 Javascript 部分のコードを `body.onload` 系のコールバック中に入れるかになると思います。`<div>` 自体の位置は、それより前であれば、どこでもかまいません。

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamoto 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。そうでございましたか、<head></head>内に入れ込んでいました。
そうなりますと、jQueryの呼び出しも上記コードの記載のように<div class='onload-on-img-onload' onload="window.alert('all resources loaded')">の直前に書き込む形になりますか？

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: ご説明のとおりに記載を行い動作するようになりました。
度々のご質問で恐縮でございますが、上記のコードのままだとアラートがでると思いますが、onloadの処理でCSSの生成は可能でございますか？CSSを生成するjQueryを書いてみましたが、動作しません。そもそもそんな事は不可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: サンプルを `$(document).ready()` を使ったものにしてみました。これだと、コードの位置を考えなくてもよいはずです。動的に作成した `<div>` に対しては、`$(xxx).enable_onload_for_images()`で機能有効にしてください。 CSS を生成するスクリプトについては別の質問の方が良いと思いますよ。（「生成する」と「変更する」で答えが変わってくるはずですのでそこは明確にするようにしてください）

Comment: 昔訊かれて答えたものがありました。普通じゃない方法も含みますが。「[Javascriptで特定のカラーを全て他の色に置き換えるには？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/4441/4978)」

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamoto 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。
新しいコードに入れ替えを行いましたが、動作しなくなりました。
CSSの質問の件、承知いたしました。「Javascriptで特定のカラーを全て他の色に置き換えるには？」を確認してみて、それでも私の力では難しそうでしたら、新しく質問を立ててみます。

Comment: たぶん。`jquery.min.js` の読み込みと前後してるのだと思います。。。コード更新しましたが、駄目な場合は、編集履歴から過去のものを拾ってください。

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamoto 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。過去のコードで問題なく動作しましたので、前回のコードを使わさせていただきます。お忙しい中、長時間お付き合いいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

全部の画像を読み込んだところで何かの処理をやりたい、ということでよろしいでしょうか。
jQueryを使うことに抵抗がないなら、非同期事象の処理はDeferredを使って片付けるのがいいと個人的にはおもいます。
こういうの、ちょちょっとプラグイン書いてしまえばすぐできますよ。こんな感じでどうでしょう？
（投稿システムの使い方にまだ慣れていないのでエラーがあるかもしれません。あったらごめんなさい）

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.fn.all_loaded = function(){
    var all_done = [];
    this.each(function(i, img){
              var promise = new $.Deferred();
              all_done.push(promise);
              img.onload = function(){
                promise.resolve();
              }
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, all_done);
  };
</script>

<div class="images">
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x100/" />
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x100/" />
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x100/" />
</div>
<script>
  $('.images img').all_loaded().done(function(){alert('all loaded')});
</script>
```

Comment: 動かないです･･･良い回答だと思いますのでぜひとも動く形でコードを共有してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
kotatsu 様 私もこれから上記コードを試させていただこうと思っています。
主に何が原因で動かないなど、参考にお聞かせいただけませんか？

Comment: 同じコードですがjsfiddleに動くものを書きました。http://jsfiddle.net/7cgjo9gk/

Comment: harry0000 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。
質問がございます。
class="images"の中のimgが実行対象ですか？
$.fn.all_loaded = function () {のコードは</body>直前に書くのが正しいですか？私が解析するればいいことを質問して申し訳ございません。

Comment: @名も無いWEB屋 `$.fn.all_loaded`のコードは、`$('.images img').all_loaded().done()` **より前** であればどこでも構いません(`head`タグ内でも`body`タグ内でも)。ただし、`</body>`直前に書くと **"より後"** になるかと思いますので動作しません。

Comment: harry0000 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。$('.images img').all_loaded().done()を$('img').all_loaded().done()にすれば、全てのimg要素が対象になりますか？全ての注意点を踏まえて実装してみますので、終了次第ご報告させていただきます。

Comment: @名も無いWEB屋 `$('img').all_loaded().done()`にした場合、この関数実行時点で存在するimgのDOMが対象になると思いますが、これらの中に既にonload()が完了してしまったimgがあると意図した通りに動作しないかもしれません。

Comment: harry0000 様 上記のコードをテストいたしましたが、読み込み中で表示されていないにも関わらず[ all loaded ]のアラートが発生します。
この処理で表示後の発火は、不可能な仕様でございますか？

Comment: @harry0000 `Deffered`~`resolve`~`when` を使った方が jQuery らしいですね。 実装の仕方参考になります。興味本位ですが少し書き換えてみました。 http://jsfiddle.net/higon/7cgjo9gk/1/ 失敗ケースを含めるて考えるとイメージ読込終了を取るのは難しいことですね...

Comment: @名も無いWEB屋 もし上記jsfiddleの初回表示時のお話をされているのであれば、単純にアラートが表示されてjsfiddleのエディタ・Resultの表示エリアを構築するJSが停止している為にそのように見えるだけかと思います。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 更新頂きありがとうございます。jQueryに詳しくなく私の回答でも無い為、恐縮です。`304`、`404`や何やかんやで色々考えることがあり意外と大変ですね…

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto もしかしたらですが、既に読み込みが完了してるimgについては`new $.Deferred();`や`all_done.push(promise);`する必要はないのかな、と思いました

Comment: 完了済の時は `all_done.push(...)` 通らなくても良いです確かに。 http://jsfiddle.net/higon/7cgjo9gk/2/ ところで、先ほど、 jQuery で画像ロード失敗を含めた完了タイミングを取るライブラリがないか調べたときに [imageLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/blob/master/imagesloaded.js) というものがありました、次にそういう処理が必要となったらこれを使ってみようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

intervalを使うのはダメですか？

```
var intv = setInterval(function(){
  if($(".target_div").length > 0){
    clearInterval(intv);
    //ここでやりたいことをやる
  }
}, 100);
```