# img要素のonloadを動的に設定する際の挙動について

Tags: javascript, html

全ての`<img>`のロードが完了した時点で処理をしたい、といった質問の回答において、`$.Deferred`を使った例が挙げられています。
（以下 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6086#comment5088_6127 よりコードを引用）

```
$.fn.all_loaded = function () {
    var all_done = new Array();
    this.each(function () {
        if ( this.complete || this.readyState === 4) 
           return;
        var promise = new $.Deferred();
        all_done.push(promise);
        this.onload = function () {
            promise.resolve();
        }
    });
    return $.when.apply($, all_done);
};

$('.images').each( function(i, holder) {
    $(holder).find('img').all_loaded().done(function() {
        if( holder.onload) holder.onload.call( holder);
    });
});
```

このコードでは`complete`や`readyState`を用いたロード済みチェックを行った後にonloadイベントの設定を行っていますが、この間にロードが完了することでonloadが呼ばれない可能性はないのでしょうか。

試しにonloadイベントを設定する直前にダミーループを仕込んで時間をかけさせてみたところ、きちんとイベントは発火しているようなのですが、規格上の根拠がないものかと探しています。

// IE8では画像がキャッシュされている際に後から設定したonloadが呼ばれないという話が
// あるようなので、逆にそれ以外では後から設定しても呼ばれるのが通例のような気はしますが。。

Comment: 画像が表示されている状態でJavascriptコンソールからonloadイベントを設定しても発火しませんから、処理中にロードが完了している場合はonloadが呼ばれない(イベントキューに積まれるのでイベントが処理されるまでの時間差はあると思います)ということでいいと思います。勘違いコメントだったらすみません。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。「スクリプトの実行中は（画像の読み込みは並行するが）イベントハンドラが実行できないのでキューに積まれ、スクリプト実行後の時点で設定されているハンドラを呼び出す」という挙動であれば自然だと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript 実行環境のシングルスレッド性の話になります。

Web ページ向け JavaScript の記述で楽なところは、 JavaScript の実行環境が基本シングルスレッドで動くことです。これにより、あるメソッド内のコードが実行中に、別の部分のコードが別のスレッドによって同時に実行されるということがありません。

シングルスレッドによる動作は、イベント処理についても同じように適用され、そこに割り込み処理という概念はありません。画像の読み込みが実質並列処理で、読み込みが完了したからと言って、「ブラウザの対応する処理が完了したその時に、実行中の JavaScript コードを割り込んで別の JavaScript コードが実行されることはない」です。

確かに、画像はブラウザによってマルチスレッドで読み込まれ、JavaScript のあるコードが実行中に、画像の読み込みが完了しているでしょうが、「画像読み込み完了によって発生する `'load'` イベント」には、現在実行中のコードが属するイベントハンドラ内のコードの実行が終了してから手がつけられます。

例えば、ページ内でイベントが次々と発生している中、 JavaScript コード(この場合 `mouseclick` イベントハンドラ)の実行が終わらない場合は、以下の簡略図ように、その間に生成されたイベントが Pending で待ち状態になっていくことでしょう。

[image: イベントハンドラスタック（想像）]

質問の `complete` プロパティの話に戻ります。 `<img>` の `complete` プロパティが `true` になるタイミングが `<img>` で指定された画像が完了し `'load'`, `'error'` イベントが発火する直前で、その変更がネイティブコードによってされるとすれば（ここはドキュメントで明確になっていない）、 JavaScript のコードから見て、 現在 `complete` が `true` でさらに `onload` が将来呼ばれるということはないといえます。

参考:

- MDN: [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)
- Webkit: [WebCore/loader/ImageLoader.cpp](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/loader/ImageLoader.cpp#L275)

Comment: ありがとうございます。となると[IEでの問題](http://please-sleep.cou929.nu/onload-handler-setting-timing-and-async-request-of-image-element.html)は、`load`イベントを同期的に実行してしまっている or そもそも実行されない、ということになるのでしょうか。

Comment: IE での問題は、キャッシュに画像が既に存在する場合、 「<img> タグを読み込んだときに 'load' イベントが発生」することです。このことで、上の図でいうと、 (order:1), (order:2) のイベントの順番が逆になります。ですので、上記のコードでは、 `readyState` プロパティを利用し、 `readyState` が既に完了の状態であれば `onload` が呼ばれることはないとしています。 /// ところで、このコードで昨日微妙だなと思ったことは別にあります。それは Internet Explorer のドキュメント ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx
 )内では `readyState` プロパティは `readystatechange` イベントハンドラ内で読まれるのが正しいと書いてあり、まだなにかありそうだと感じさせられたところでした。もしも `readyState` プロパティの設定タイミングがずれるのであれば、上記コードでは完了タイミングの取得に失敗する可能性があるからです。ですので、上記のコードで大体は安心はできるだろうけれど、厳密にやるならば、バッドノウハウを詰めたライブラリを使った方が楽かなとは感じています。