# JavaScript で Base64 エンコードをして Canvas に画像を表示

Tags: javascript, 画像, html5-canvas

```
 function addMessage (value,color,size) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("picture");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
    var image.src  = " &quot;data:image/jpg;base64," + window.btoa(value) + "&quot;";
    image.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
    var msg = value.replace( /[!@$%<>'"&|]/g, '' );
    $("#msg_list").prepend("<div class='msg'>"  + msg + "</div>");
  }
```

Android から画像をサーバー経由で送り、ブラウザで表示したいのですがうまくいきません。

Android 側ではイメージをバイナリデータにして、ブラウザ側で処理しやすいようにと思い、  string にして送っています。 Android 側、ブラウザ側ともに表示される string は同じなのでサーバー側には問題はないように思います。

JavaScript 側のコードしかのせていませんが、どなたかご存知の方、書き方が正しいかどうか見ていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`var image.src`としているため、エラーとなっていませんか？
未検証ですがこれで動くと思います。

```
function addMessage (value,color,size) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("picture");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
    image.src  = "data:image/jpg;base64," + window.btoa(value);

    var msg = value.replace( /[!@$%<>'"&|]/g, '' );
    $("#msg_list").prepend("<div class='msg'>"  + msg + "</div>");
}
```

参考(Pierreさんの回答)：
[Convert and insert Base64 data to Canvas in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473205/convert-and-insert-base64-data-to-canvas-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`value` の中身が正しいかどうか分からないので、他にもあるかもしれませんが、 `&quot;` が必要ないのと、 `onload` を登録している行の位置が心配です。

具体的には

```
var image.src  = " &quot;data:image/jpg;base64," + window.btoa(value) + "&quot;";
```

の行を

```
var image.src  = "data:image/jpg;base64," + window.btoa(value);
```

とし、 `onload` の行は `image.src` の設定前に移動する感じです。（[関連](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6206/4978)）